# Why is ./configure libbitcoin-system not finding boost library on Raspian Butch?

Tags: c++, boost, raspberry-pi, raspbian

**tl;dr: `Boost` was there, but had issues. The `./configure` did not know the path to `boost`.**

---

I did clone for `libbitcoin-system` and did `git checkout v3.6.0` and followed [this](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system#autotools-advanced-users) (logs are below):

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig
```

`./configure` exits with

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.62.0... yes
configure: boost_CPPFLAGS : -I/usr/include
configure: boost_ISYS_CPPFLAGS : -isystem/usr/include
configure: boost_LDFLAGS : -L/usr/lib
configure: boost_BUILD_CPPFLAGS : -I/usr/include
checking whether the Boost::Chrono library is available... yes
configure: error: Could not find a version of the library!
```

I am running a **Raspbian Buster on a RP3B**. I did install [bitcoin core](https://github.com/bitcoin) and it runs well. I did not install `boost` but it is on my system.

---

First I thought something is wrong with `boost`. Following a comment I found with `sudo find /usr -type f -name "libboost*.so*"`:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_iostreams.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_program_options.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_date_time.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_atomic.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_iostreams.so.1.58.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_system.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_thread.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_locale.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_chrono.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_timer.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_regex.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_wserialization.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_filesystem.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_serialization.so.1.67.0
```

**So I suspect everything is fine with `boost`, right?** (EDIT: No, it was not.)

---

Here is the full log after `./configure`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/libbitcoin-system $ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ar... ar
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
checking build system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking host system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf file names to armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... yes
checking --with-pkgconfigdir option... ${exec_prefix}/lib/pkgconfig
checking --with-tests option... yes
checking --with-examples option... yes
checking --with-icu option... no
checking --with-png option... no
checking --with-qrencode option... no
checking --enable-ndebug option... yes
checking --enable-isystem option... no
checking for boostlib >= 1.62.0... yes
configure: boost_CPPFLAGS : -I/usr/include
configure: boost_ISYS_CPPFLAGS : -isystem/usr/include
configure: boost_LDFLAGS : -L/usr/lib
configure: boost_BUILD_CPPFLAGS : -I/usr/include
checking whether the Boost::Chrono library is available... yes
configure: error: Could not find a version of the library!
```

Output of `$ ./autogen.sh`:

```
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build-aux'.
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
configure.ac:36: installing 'build-aux/ar-lib'
configure.ac:36: installing 'build-aux/compile'
configure.ac:39: installing 'build-aux/config.guess'
configure.ac:39: installing 'build-aux/config.sub'
configure.ac:30: installing 'build-aux/install-sh'
configure.ac:30: installing 'build-aux/missing'
Makefile.am: installing 'build-aux/depcomp'
parallel-tests: installing 'build-aux/test-driver'
```

After I got the error the first time I installed `libbitcoin-secp256k1` from [source](https://github.com/libbitcoin/secp256k1) which worked fine.

---

EDIT: Following a comment I told `./configure` where to find `boost` and this helped a bit but now it is exiting with `boost_iostreams`:

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.62.0... yes
configure: boost_CPPFLAGS : -I/usr/include
configure: boost_ISYS_CPPFLAGS : -isystem/usr/include
configure: boost_LDFLAGS : -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
configure: boost_BUILD_CPPFLAGS : -I/usr/include
checking whether the Boost::Chrono library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_chrono... yes
configure: boost_chrono_LIBS : -lboost_chrono
checking whether the Boost::Date_Time library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_date_time... yes
configure: boost_date_time_LIBS : -lboost_date_time
checking whether the Boost::Filesystem library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_filesystem... yes
configure: boost_filesystem_LIBS : -lboost_filesystem
checking whether the Boost::IOStreams library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_iostreams... no
checking for exit in -lboost_iostreams... (cached) no
configure: error: Could not link against boost_iostreams !
```

---

EDIT: Following another comment I updated `boost_iostreams` from [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libboost-iostreams1.67-dev) with `sudo apt install libboost-iostreams1.67-dev` which installed the `armhf`-file in the right place.

Now the `./configure` is exiting with

```
checking whether the Boost::Locale library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_locale... no
configure: error: Could not link against boost_locale !
```

---

**I solved it with `sudo apt install libboost-dev`.** I was reluctant to do this because I read other comments where people did it and it still did not work and I wanted to find out what is specifically wrong with my (pre)-installation of `boost` on my Raspian Butch.

Comment: boost doesn't generate a "boost.so" file in any versions I've used. Try instead : `find /usr -type f -name "libboost*.so*"`

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thanks! I found files and updated my question. But it is probably another question now. :)

Comment: You need to look in the configure log file to see what its looking for and what it didn't find

Comment: If `sudo apt install libboost-iostreams1.67-dev` fixed your problem with `boost-iostreams`can you guess the command to fix problems with `boost-locale`? you probably want to run `sudo apt install libboost-dev`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, I understand. But the 67-file for locale was there, on the contrary to the iostream, which was another version. Also, in other questions and comments installing 'libboost-dev' did not solve the problem and I was not sure if I mess things up with it. But it worked, thanks. I still had to give the path, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you found the boost shared objects in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/` (using `find /usr -type f -name "libboost*.so*"`), you'll have to let the configure script know to look for the boost libraries in that location :

```
./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

followed by the rest of the build commands (make etc.).

Comment: This helped, but I now got an error with `boost_iostreams`. I updated it in the question at the bottom.

Comment: @Ben : note that the iostreams library you have installed (`/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_iostreams.so.1.58.0`) is an older version. You'll want to make sure you have the 1.67 version for that as well.